# Los hilos de mi executor no se ejecutan en orden

Tags: java, hilos, executorservice

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que escriba en un fichero mediante la clase RandomAccessFile de forma paralela y en exclusión mutua.

A la hora de compilar y ejecutar funciona, el problema llega cuando, al abrir el fichero, veo que las letras están en orden pero que algunas letras no están y sólo dejan un espacio.

```
public class ficheroSeguro extends Thread implements Runnable{
//macro para el fichero
static final String MiArchivo = 
"C:/Users/Raul_/Desktop/PCTR 7/ficheroSeguroTexto.txt";
//cadena que pasamos al constructor
static String palabrasfichero;
//contador para ver el orden en que se ejecutan
int i;
public ficheroSeguro(String S,int i){
    this.palabrasfichero = S;
    this.i=i;
}

public synchronized void run(){
    long threadId = ficheroSeguro.currentThread().getId();
    System.out.println("Ejecutando el hilo: " +threadId+ "con valor: " +i);
    try{
    writeData(MiArchivo,palabrasfichero,i);
    }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Error en metodo run");}
}



public static void writeData(String S, String data, int i) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile raf1 = new RandomAccessFile(MiArchivo, "rw");
    raf1.seek(i);
    raf1.writeChar(palabrasfichero.charAt(i));
    raf1.close();
}   



public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile (MiArchivo,"rw");
        raf.setLength(0);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){System.out.println("Error al abrir");}
     catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Error al vaciar");}
    String cadena = sc.next();
    //ejecutor con tantos hilos como tamaño tenga la cadena
    ExecutorService exe= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cadena.length());
    for(int i = 0; i<cadena.length();i++){
        exe.execute(new ficheroSeguro(cadena,i));
    }
    exe.shutdown();
    exe.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}



}`
```

Cuando lo ejecuto e imprime por pantalla el system.out del run aparecen los hilos con un orden distinto

```
Ejecutando el hilo: 14con valor: 1
Ejecutando el hilo: 12con valor: 0
Ejecutando el hilo: 16con valor: 2
Ejecutando el hilo: 18con valor: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Si ejecutas tu programa varias veces, probablemente observarás que el orden en que los hilos corren varía a cada vez.  ¡Esto es 100% normal!

Cuando ejecutas varios hilos en paralelo, no existe ninguna garantía en cuanto al orden en que ejecutarán. De hecho, hasta es posible que el hilo `A` comienze a ejecutar antes que el hilo `B`, pero el hilo `B` termine su ejecución antes del hilo `A`. Todo esto depende enteramente de como el sistema operativo le asigna tiempo CPU a cada hilo.

Si necesitas que tu código ejecute de forma secuencial, entonces no deberías usar hilos.

---

Notas aparte. Tu programa tiene muchos detalles raros que valdría la pena revisar también. Te cito algunos ejemplos:

- No necesitas que tu clase herede de `Thread`. Con que implemente `Runnable` es suficiente y lo recomendable.
- No es normal que el constructor de instancia esté asignando a una variable estática. En este caso, no es un problema, porque siempre le estás asignando el mismo valor, pero el diseño es incorrecto.
- El `synchronized` en tu método `run` no cumple ninguna función, ya que un solo thread puede correr este método para una instancia de `ficheroSeguro`.
- Lo que probablemente sí requiere cierta syncronización es el método `writeData`, pero no bastaría con agregarle `synchronized`. Habría que sincronizar con algún miembro estático. Pero si vas a hacer esto, nuevamente cuestiono el propósito de usar hilos.

Comment: Y cómo puedo asegurarme que corran en orden porque el programa tengo que hacerlo en paralelo

Comment: Fácil. No uses hilos. Pedir que algo se haga en orden pero a la vez en paralelo es una contradicción.